# Timeout problem between CosmosDB Emulator and Pymongo

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo

I'm facing to this problem : i can't connect to a Cosmos Db Emulator with Pymongo. I have the following issue :

```
Can't connect:localhost:10255: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 641990428201d2b41cc63b8f, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('localhost:10255: timed out')>]>
```

I followed the Microsoft documentation to start the lastest version the emulator using this command line :

```
PS C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> .\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6
```

This is the code inspired from Azure Cosmos Emulator 's github to connect to the emulator :

```
import pymongo

# </package_dependencies>

def main():
    """Connect to the API for MongoDB"""

    try:
        # <client_credentials>
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true", tls=True, tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True)

        for prop, value in vars(client.options).items():
            print("Property: {}: Value: {} ".format(prop, value))
        # </client_credentials>
        try:
            client.server_info()  # validate connection string
        except (
            pymongo.errors.OperationFailure,
            pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure,
            pymongo.errors.ExecutionTimeout,
        ) as err:
            sys.exit("Can't connect:" + str(err))
    except Exception as err:
        sys.exit("Error:" + str(err))

    print("Connected to MongoDB")

    # <client_disconnect>
    client.close()
    # </client_disconnect>


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried differents start commands to run the emulator like `/NoFirewall`, `/AllowNetworkAccess /KeyFile=cosmosdbauthkey` and many others because it seems that the emulator is inaccessible.

Note that the emulator and the test code are running on the same computer.

This is really strange because i'm able to be connected with one time every 50 tries... Any ideas ?

Comment: i think you need `/AllowNetworkAccess`, also, try port `10250`? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48295

Comment: Python console output when I try /AllowNetworkAccess and /MongoPort : `Can't connect:localhost:10255: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6419ac9a267331ebafc9e05f, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:10255: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée')>]>`

Comment: still says 255, not 250

Comment: I forget to change the connection stream provide by Azure Cosmos DB Emulator front page to `mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@**localhost:10255**/admin?ssl=true`  
I have the following error now : `Can't connect:localhost:10250: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6419b2ca18aa94627749ae3e, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 10250) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('localhost:10250: timed out')>]>`

Comment: are you using `/AllowNetworkAccess`?

Comment: Yes, the start command is `PS C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> .\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6 /AllowNetworkAccess /KeyFile=cosmosdbauthkey /MongoPort=10250`